# Загрузка текстур в OpenGL из Bitmap

Tags: bitmap, c++, opengl

Доброго времени суток!

Поступила задача написать *2D*-игру на *OpenGL*. В логике игры проблем не возникло - не первый подобный проект, но с *OpenGL* я работаю впервые, поэтому появилось множество вопросов. Почти все решились или сами собой, или после первого запроса в гугле.

Но последняя проблема, кажется, самая серьёзная. Нужно отображать 16 видов текстур для разных игровых объектов, и на этапе их загрузки возникли трудности. Нашёл [здесь](http://www.nullterminator.net/gltexture.html)
пример, но так и не смог реализовать его для *Bitmap* (каждая текстура у меня хранится в отдельном *.bmp файле).

Пожалуйста, помогите на примере разобраться, что к чему.

Comment: а что насчет хранения текстур не в bmp?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20595340/loading-a-tga-bmp-file-in-c-opengl
принятый ответ, вроде грузит tga и bmp. не уверен, что нашлось

Comment: Спасибо, вторая ссылка выглядит как прямой ответ на мой вопрос. Сейчас уже поздно, завтра попробую реализовать по примеру.

Comment: @Богдан Бессонов, сделал как в принятом ответе по второй ссылке. Теперь вместо текстуры отображается сплошной цвет, близкий к среднему на самой текстуре. Не понимаю, из-за чего такое, гугл не помог...

Comment: Второй ответ на Стеке вообще стремный какой-то. У БМПэхи вообще-то, как и у большинства других форматов имеется заголовок, а в представленной ф-и он игнорируется + размеры рисунка забиты наглухо, и какая глубина цвета у файла, тоже не совсем понятно. По формату BMP есть инфа в http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP . Первый ссылка на ответ на Стеке, приведенная @Богдан Бессонов, похожа на правду, попробуйте код с нее.

Comment: @MDJHD, я уже разобрался, второй ответ подошёл, а ошибка с отображением была зарыта не в загрузке из битмапа.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для загрузки текстур из *.bmp подошёл принятый ответ по [вот этой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12518111/how-to-load-a-bmp-on-glut-to-use-it-as-a-texture) ссылке.

Но, думаю, другим новичкам в OpenGL может быть полезно решение дальнейшей моей ошибки (когда вместо текстуры отображался сплошной цвет, близкий к цвету текстуры). У меня был вот такой код для отображения объектов:

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(i*129, j*129);              glVertex2i(i*129, j*129);
    glTexCoord2i(i*129 + 128, j*129);        glVertex2i(i*129 + 128, j*129);
    glTexCoord2i(i*129 + 128, j*129 + 128);  glVertex2i(i*129 + 128, j*129 + 128);
    glTexCoord2i(i*129, j*129 + 128);        glVertex2i(i*129, j*129 + 128);
glEnd();
```

Собственно, правильный код (исправил методом тыка, уже потом понял, почему это правильно):

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 1);  glVertex2i(i*129, j*129);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 1);  glVertex2i(i*129 + 128, j*129);
    glTexCoord2i(1, 0);  glVertex2i(i*129 + 128, j*129 + 128);
    glTexCoord2i(0, 0);  glVertex2i(i*129, j*129 + 128);
glEnd();
```

Спасибо @Богдан Бессонов и @MDJHD.